# How to trigger expensive build steps only when required?

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity project with the following build configurations:

1. Gather dependencies (expensive)
2. Build
3. Test
4. Deploy

Say I know whether I need to do it by changes to some file `deps.txt`.

Here's what I want to do:

- I want to trigger builds on all changes in version control.
- If `deps.txt` has changed, I want to run builds 1, then 2, then 3, then 4.
- If `deps.txt` has not changed, I want to run builds 2 then 3 then 4.

I tried putting triggers on build configurations like this:

1. VCS trigger on no checkins, unless `+:deps.txt`
2. VCS tigger on all checkins, unless `-:deps.txt`
3. Snapshot dependency on 2, trigger when 2 finishes building
4. Snapshot dependency on 3, trigger when 3 finishes building

but if a commit includes changes deps.txt *and* other files, then configurations 1 and 2 trigger at the same time, meaning that configuration 2 will fail.

Is there an easy way to do this in TeamCity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest a different approach:

a. Creating duplicate build configuration

b. Triggering the whole build chain from the last build.

The first chain of Build Configurations:

1. Gather dependencies: no trigger
2. Build: snapshot and artifact dependency on 1 on the same build chain, no trigger
3. Test: snapshot and artifact dependency on 2 on the same build chain, no trigger
4. Deploy: snapshot and artifact dependency on 3 on the same chain, VCS trigger on +:deps.txt

The second chain of Build Configurations:

5. Build: snapshot and artifact dependency on 1 on Last successful build, no trigger
6. Test: snapshot and artifact dependency on 5 on the same chain, no trigger
7. Deploy: snapshot and artifact dependency on 6 on the same chain, VCS trigger on any change -:deps.txt

In order to reduce duplicates you may use templates for 2 and 5, 3 and 6, 4 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine 1 into 2, and then for the build step of 1 which gathers dependencies, write a custom script which uses the `teamcity.build.changedFiles.file` property (see [TeamCity docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Predefined+Build+Parameters)) to check if deps.txt has actually changed or not, and then either gather dependencies or not.  The rest of the build steps from 2 would then proceed as normal.